# Free memory point manipulation in solmate library

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

I am trying to learn a little bit of yul and came across a scenario in the solmate library I don't quite understand. In all of the instances when they are appending addresses to the free memory pointer rather than using increases of 20 they use increases of 22. Why do they do it this way as opposed to using 20?

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you doing the yul course on Udemy. And learning memory slot patterns.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking a contract they have to encode the parameters using the [Contract ABI](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html).

In the specification all fixed size parameters should be padded to 32 bytes. An address parameters, which is 20 bytes, should be padded to 32 bytes.